# (In iOS/OS X SDK's) Where are __i386__ and __x86_64__ defined?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, ios-simulator, preprocessor-directive

In iOS and OS X SDK's, where are those architecture values defined?

The reason I am interested is because I used to conditionally compile code for the iOS Simulator as follows:

```
#ifdef __i386__
   // Simulator-only code
#endif
```

And just noticed that I haven't updated it for the new 64-bit iOS Simulator by also checking for `__x86_64__`, and I'm also curious about other defines as there doesn't seem to be an official Apple documentation file for this.

Comment: If you command click them in Xcode, you should be taken to their definitions.  Did you try that?  (It might be a define introduced by the compiler though)

Comment: As a side note, why not just use the `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` define?  That's what it is there for.

Comment: Command+click was the first thing I tried -> "Symbol not found". As for `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`, I was trying it with `#ifdef` which was always true as it is always defined (either equal to `0` or `1`). It now works with just `#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values are defined by CLANG at compilation time depending on the target you happen to be building for, but were formalized by the GNU C spec for use in GCC.

Comment: So there's no "place" to see them (and what else gets defined)?

Comment: No, nor should there be.  The compiler is given the arguments it needs to output a binary for a specific architecture, why should it keep around a header file filled with conditionals?

Comment: Right. I guess I could "see" them in the `CompileC *.m normal i386` commands.